# Symfony | Twig - <Form> tag is not displayed

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony, twig

I'm currently working on removing users, but a very strange event has appeared.

From my view I can remove users through a list of deleteForm.

In my controller :

```
$deleteForms = array();
        foreach ($organisation->getMembers() as $entity) {
            $deleteForms[$entity->getId()] = $this->createDeleteForm($entity)->createView();
        }
```

And I get what I want on my view:
[image: myview]

It is normal that there is not the button for the first.
[image]

Deletion works correctly **EXCEPT** for the first user who owns the button

Here is the generated html code:[image]

As you can see, the form tag does not appear. Even if I put a url directly or otherwise, the form tag is never displayed.

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: why don't you use symfony forms ?

Comment: It's a symfony form, what do you mean ? 
I need a form for each user in a for loop

Comment: so you don't need to write the `form` , the hidden input and the submit button your self, just let symfony handle it

Comment: I did this like this, is that what you meant?
`{{ form_start(deleteForms[member.id])}}
{{ form_widget(deleteForms[member.id]) }}
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                                                        </button>
{{ form_end(form) }}`

Comment: I get the same result as before, the first does not have a form tag

Comment: Did you check the *generated* code? What you're showing is the *parsed* code, they may differ. Check the generated html for syntax errors, like unclosed tags.